# AspectJ dependency missing in spring boot 2.1.1

Tags: spring-boot, aspectj, spring-initializr

I was trying to create a new `Spring Boot` project using `start.spring.io`. Searching for dependencies, I found that there was no `AspectJ` starter available. Has this dependency removed/deprecated from `Spring Boot` starters? Here is a screen shot:
[image: Spring boot starter does not show AspectJ dependency]

I, however, was able to find the dependency on maven repositories website:

[image: Spring boot starter AOP on maven repository]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was removed indeed. @jwenting explained in a nutshell why. This starer is required if you want to create your own aspect or if you want to use some advanced AOP mode.

Most users don't need it and whenever a library requires it, its starter brings it automatically. Having a dedicated entry was confusing as we saw a very large amount of users picking this up for no good reason.

Also, please keep in mind that start.spring.io is not an exhaustive list of what you can do with Spring. We're focusing on the getting started experience only and avoiding cases that could lead to confusion. This one is a good example of the latter.

Comment: Do you mean that the starter still exists - just not in `start.spring.io` as I was able to get it using `spring-boot-starter-aop` and it works as expected?

Comment: As I've stated, It's not an exhaustive list. So if something is not on start.spring.io, it doesn't mean it's removed. It doesn't mean we don't recommend it (anymore). It just means we didn't feel it is a candidate for a getting started experience.

Comment: Thanks @Stephane for your explanation

Answer (score 1):

it's an implicit dependency, meaning you don't have to include it because it's automatically pulled in by anything that needs it.

You can still add it explicitly, but there's no need to (and afaik it's never been needed).

Comment: This does not seem to be true. I tried `mvn dependency:tree` but it shows no traces of `AOP` library.

Comment: Adding the later dependency `spring-boot-starter-aop` does show `AspectJ` on the classpath.